# How to restore leather texture after water damage

Tags: restoration, leather

This leather bag got caught in a heavy shower, and got drenched with water. After it dried up, the texture changed. You can see the damage on the bottom left side. It's wrinkly, and the granular texture is different (it has larger grains).

[image]

Is there anything I can do to restore it as best as possible? I already applied leather conditioner, but it didn't help.

Comment: How long ago was the shower? To me it looks like the bottom corner is more "moisturized" than the rest, making it swell up a bit. It may slowly return to its former texture if you let it dry more, from the inside and outside. Make sure there are no wrinkles in the leather while it dries or they may become permanent.

Comment: This happened 5 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer per se, but...

Some stretching / pressing might help, but I am reluctant. Some kind of oily "massage" might help also.

Please note that if the leather is "floating" (not glued to a non-stretch reinforcing material) you can end up with curls instead of wrinkles - which would be quite bad.

---

As a matter of fact, my initial reaction (before reading the text) was that the problem was in the upper part of the picture. So, if you wear that wallet in the rear pocket of your pants for a while, you should get your desired effect without any additional effort (besides carrying it with you).

---

If I were you, I would just embrace the new personality of the wallet, rather than risk destroying it. To anyone else besides you, the wallet looks exactly as it was supposed to look.